# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in...soap issue

Tags: php, soap

I've got this error while printing my result from wsdl..Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in.

```
  $scramble = $client->getMobile($origtext); 
  print("$scramble");
```

so i use var dump and here is what i got

```
  var_dump($scramble);

  Arrayobject(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["phone-num"]=> string(2) "VH" }
```

yes! string "VH" is exactly what i need to print but the problem is..how?
should i use something like

```
   $scramble = $client->getMobile($origtext)->Arrayobject("phone-num");
```

but it for sure output undefined function error...any one knows whats the method i should be using to print out he string?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try casting `$scramble` to an `array`? Also it makes absolutely *no* sense to write `"$scramble"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$scramble = $client->getMobile($origtext)->{"phone-num"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the inner value by it's arrayobject key:

```
$scramble = $client->getMobile($origtext); 
print($scramble["phone-num"]);
```